# Where should data formatting be done?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Suppose that I have 2 scenarios, 1 is fetching data from api via `componentDidMount()` and another is fetching via `redux actions` with `redux-thunk` which has an array of data return (u all can think it as a product list return). Where exactly i should do a data formatting (eg: format currency and datetime).

I am currently doing the data formatting in `render()`. Using a component like `react-moment` also means the data formatting done in `render()`

But I also learn that data should be process and transformed outside of render for best performance. However, most of the solution i see online did those formatting inside `render()` instead of format it after getting the return data in `componentDidMount()`.

So which is which? is the performance of formatting data inside `render()` is insignificant compare to the hassle needed. Note that I am talking about array of objects being displayed not an object.

Comment: Why not in the action creator before the payload gets dispatched the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how often your data needs to be formatted. If you put it in the render method, it will be formatted every time the render method is called.

If it only needs to be formatted once, do it in your componentDidMount, your action or mapStateToProps.

If you see people doing this in render, it's probably just to keep the example simple. Really, I would almost never do this unless there is nowhere else to do it.

Comment: 99% of example in the top search result doing formatting in render. Using a react component library like react-moment and react-currency-formatter also means doing it in render (correct me if am wrong). So i would wonder is the performance impact insignificant compare to the hassle needed?

Comment: It depends on the size of your application. Again, this is done mostly in examples, not production applications. Always try to minimize the work in render so it's not being done multiple times if not needed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think it depends on your specific scenario.

From my experience, most of the formatting helper should be in the last phase before displaying it onto the UI. In this specific case I think it's totally fine to have it in `render`. There are a few reasons why we should have put it there:

- You're centralizing the source and keep it as simple as it could. Think about working with different timezone and you need to keep track of stuff like schedule. You won't want to format it right from the beginning.
- Separating the formatter into a helper function will be easier for unit test purpose, from here you can extend that into many purposes.
- You can put this in the selector phase of `mapStateToProps`
- You can easily prevent a re-render if the value doesn't change from the last render, that's just a simple check case and still not affect much within your application.
- There will be a trade-off when it comes to performance optimization, some will take a whole lot re-work and for business, time effort costs money. So you should also have put this into consideration too. If the changes doesn't create a great difference, then we should focus on other factors first because I'm pretty sure there are still a lot of rooms to improve within your products.